# Array returning NIL in Swift 5

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, swift5

I recently converted to Swift 5. I'm attempting to parse a json array that has values for all fields. The data is stored in MySQL. Here is a sample of the data:

```
Optional({
age = 33;
date = "2019-12-28 00:15:14";
messagetext = "test";
notesid = 1497;
recipient = duce;
"recipient_id" = 50;
"reply_id" = 0;
sender = tester1234;
"sender_id" = 345;
uid = 345;
username = tester1234;
uuid = "4C8F145E-C411-469E-8D31-057500B80BBC";
zip = 60608;
```

I'm using the below code to get the values:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                    self.hhmessages.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                                           guard let parseJSON = json else {
                                               print("Error while parsing")
                                               return
                                           }

                    guard let posts = parseJSON["messages"] else {
                                               print("Error while parseJSONing")
                                               return
                                           }
                    self.hhmessages = posts
                    let test = self.hhmessages["sender"] as? String

                    for i in 0 ..< self.hhmessages.count {

                        let member = self.hhmessages[i]?["sender"] as? Member
                        let text = self.hhmessages[i]?["messagetext"] as? String
                        let uuid = self.hhmessages[i]?["uuid"]
}
```

When I run the app and print the values it crashes and says the values are NIL.  It worked prior to my conversion to Swift 5 and integration of MessageKit.

Comment: First, your posted structure doesn't match how the code is parsing it, so I don't know if that's a oversight on your part or the problem.  Also `messagetext` is not the right key. `let test = self.hhmessages["sender"] as? String` doesn't seem right based on the context you are using it

Comment: You shouldn't be using NSDictionary when coding in Swift. Swift native dictionary type is `[String: Any]`. Btw `options: .mutableContainers` is pointless. Just omit it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I didn't copy the entire array sample set and definitely didn't put it in the right format, I was just trying to show there was data there.  My array is for a chat and contains sender, uuid and text.  Right now sender is coming back nil. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks for the feedback. Is that contributing to my error?

Comment: @techgirl don't waste your time with `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`. Take a look at Swift `Codable` protocol

Comment: `JSONSerialization` is good when your data structure is ambiguous. However, if you have a well-known format, @LeoDabus is right -> you should create a `Codable` model and just use `JSONDecoder()` to deserialize.

Comment: Thanks @zaitsman, my data is stored in MySQL and I'm using PHP for my API. I used JSONSerialization based on a class I took.

Comment: Well the other thing is that even with your code `values it crashes and says the values are NIL` -> where does it crash? what values are nil? Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: @zaitsman, yes I've stepped through the code. The test variable I put in was to show me if the nil was happening before or after the loop.  It's happening before on the member value.

Comment: @techgirl it thoroughly sounds like something in the actual code just doesn't match the actual JSON :/ short of debugging the code with you I don't think I can help from the listing you posted

Comment: Thanks for trying @zaitsman, there was no issue with it prior to my conversion. I'll keep researching

Comment: @techgirl i'd look in your source control at what has changed in this file and in any classes along the call stack.

Comment: It would help to have [enough information to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You mention that you are trying to parse a JSON array, so show an example of the JSON array and then show the code that you're using to parse it. Showing that you have data in a format that doesn't match your question does not help you get your question answered. And, of course, do follow @zaitsman's advice and check your code for recent changes.